# issue with inline-block elements

Tags: html, css-float, css

I am trying to make a screen that is similar to the "metro" design in principle.

The way that I am going at it is that all elements are the same width, but not the same height. They should then all align to the top and figure out what empty space there is free, **not leaving any space above them**.

The problem I am having is that if I set the elements to inline-block they render like this:
[image]

If I set them to float, one side looks right, but the other one does not. Here is for both float:left and float:right:
[image]
[image]

Here is a fiddle with the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/paulocoelho/2qyrp/

Tze code:

```
div{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin:1px;
    /*float:left;*/
}

.smallBlock{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background:blue;
}
.largeBlock{
    height:90px;
    width:50px;
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: I am also looking for a non-JS solution...

Comment: Do the large tiles have to be elongated vertically? Windows 8 style would be horizontal.

Comment: I think windows 8 blocks can be elongated both ways (vert and horiz). For this example the height is variable but the width is fixed.

Comment: I don't think you can do this without JS unless you use tables, but that would also require you to use set widths

Comment: It might not be very difficult to use a jQuery to walk through all of the divs and position them absolute in an array format of your choosing. Do you need them to reflow if the browser window is resized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you'll want this to be dynamic, it will only be possible with CSS3, using multiple columns, and in case you need it to be responsive you'll need media queries.

I've found a [tutorial](http://designshack.net/articles/css/masonry/) that shows you how to do this, haven't tested it out myself but seems like it should work.

Anyways i'll recommend you doing this with JS, you'll have alot more control over it and also get it to be cross-browser.

Comment: The non-CSS solution you gave me works. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/paulocoelho/2qyrp/12/ And its fun, because I am also from Funchal. HA! :P Obrigado :)

Comment: I'm glad i was able to help you out. It's a small world eheh :)

Comment: ** just a correction to my previous comment. I ment non-JS, not non-CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Structure the layout as columns that stretch vertically and fill each column in turn with the variable height elements.